# Symfony 5 Invalid firewall "api": user provider "app_user_provider" not found

Tags: symfony

When i add a new firewall for use api Authentication , i get this fail:

**Invalid firewall "api": user provider "app_user_provider" not found.**

how i can fix this fail?

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 4
    
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
        proveedor:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login
                provider: proveedor
                default_target_path: tasks
                
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: app_user_provider
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\TokenAuthenticator
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your firewall named 'api', you specify 'app_user_provider' but in it is not present in the providers list.

In the providers list, you have: in_memory and proveedor.

Try to replace app_user_provider by proveedor.
If the provider allow you to get your user, it should work.